# HttpPost to REST WCF Service - Geting empty table when try to send DataTable

Tags: java, wcf, rest, httpclient

I need to test a .Net method in a REST WCF Service, that require passing in a DataTable and also return a DataTable:

```
DataTable TryPostDataTable(DataTable dataTable);
```

In my Java test code, I used HtttClient to send a Post request to this service. It has the header:

```
"Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
```

and body:

```
  <TryPostDataTable xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <dataTable>
      <Person>
        <name>A Name</name>
        <age>An Age</age>
      </Person>
    </dataTable>
  </TryPostDataTable>
```

But when the service receive the request, the dataTable variable always become an empty DataTable instance, with no rows and columns

If I change the dataTable's type to String, and change the Post body to :

```
  <TryPostDataTable xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <datatable>
      TestString
    </datatable>
  </TryPostDataTable>
```

Then it parses the request properly.

I can not figure out how to pass a DataTable object through HttpPost. What is wrong with the parsing process from XML to DataTable in the Rest service? Or my Post is not correct?

Any help will be really appreciated.

//Edit 1:

I tried to used this code to generate the xml content:

```
DataTable dtEmployee = new DataTable("Person");                             
        dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));        
        dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(string));             
        dtEmployee.Rows.Add("A Name", "An Age");                        
        dtEmployee.WriteXml(@"C:\Working\Employee.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

which will generate:

```
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Person" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Person">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

```
<Person>
    <Name>A Name</Name>
    <Age>An Age</Age>
  </Person>
```

Then I use httpPost to send this xml to the TryPostDataTable method.

The Service now successfully parse the schema and generate a "Person" table, with 2 columns "Name" - "Age", assigned to variable dataTable. But with no row - no data inside.

Comment: can you show your person class? my guess would be its not serializable?

Comment: @Chris I do not have the Person class. Should the services parse my xml to a DataTable , with has name "Person", 2 columns "name" - "age", and one row "A Name" - "An Age"?

Comment: No - you're trying to post a datatable with a property of type Person, which has string properties name and age.

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure about this. The xml is generated by the following code: DataTable dt = new DataTable("Person"); dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string)); dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(string)); dt.Rows.Add("A Name", "An Age"); dt.WriteXml(@"C:\Working\Employee.xml"); So I just pass back the result to the HttpPost body, but it generated a empty DataTable instance. I do not want a typed DataTable, could you please provide an example xml or a google keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my REST method on the server as below:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke]
public DataTable GetMyDataTable(DataTable dt)
        {
            DataTable returnTable  = new DataTable("ServerTable");
            returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "FirstName", DataType = typeof(String)});
            returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "LastName", DataType = typeof(String) });

            if (dt.Columns.Count == 2 && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return returnTable;
            }
            else
            {
                returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "MiddleName", DataType = typeof(String) });
                return returnTable;
            }
        }
```

Your raw request when calling the web service should look as below:

```
POST http://localhost/SampleService/Service1.svc/GetMyDataTable HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 1022
Host: rajeshwin7

<DataTable xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data"><xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="SampleTable" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="SampleTable"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"><DocumentElement xmlns=""><SampleTable diffgr:id="SampleTable1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><FirstName>MyFirst</FirstName><LastName>MyLast</LastName></SampleTable></DocumentElement></diffgr:diffgram></DataTable>
```

The response i got back from my server was as below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 804
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 17:07:37 GMT

<DataTable xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data"><xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="ServerTable" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="ServerTable"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"/></DataTable>
```

I did POST the raw request and response as captured by Fiddler. Just monitor on how your request looks like and that should help you get your access to the REST service without any problem. Also the data table should have a name else it would fail to serialize and deserialize.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. By adding the tag <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"> now it can parse the data \:D/

Answer (score 0):

It is better to to convert whole table into List
like this , I used :-

```
public List<user> fulldata()
        {

            string ConnectString = "server=localhost;database=test_local;integrated security=SSPI";
            string QueryString = "select * from tbl_register";

            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectString);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryString, myConnection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Register Table");


            List<user> ls = new List<user>();
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                user res = new user();
                res.name = row["name"].ToString();
                res.company = row["cname"].ToString();
                res.address = row["address"].ToString();
                ls.Add(res);
            }
            return ls;
        }

        public class user
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string company { get; set; }
            public string address { get; set; }
        }
```